# Outputting the contents of files with an extra line break in between each

Tags: linux, bash, cat

I have two files with no line break at the end of the file. So when I call "cat file1 file2", the last line of file1 and the first line of file2 share a line. I need a command that will output the files correctly. I can't change the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your files are by themselves in the pwd:

```
for i in *; do cat "$i" && echo ""; done
```

Otherwise, you will need to create an array:

```
files=( "file0" "file1" "file2" )
for i in "${files[@]}"; do cat "$i" && echo ""; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use awk:

```
awk 1 file1 file2
```

Comment: or `sed '' file1 file2`.

Comment: or `sed b file1 file2`.

Answer (score 2):

You can very simply add a `newline` after `file 1` and before `file 2` with:

```
$ cat f1 <(echo "") f2
```

**Example:**

```
$ printf "line1\nline2" > f1
$ printf "line3\nline4" > f2
$ cat f1 f2
line1
line2line3
line4
```

**With fix:**

```
$ cat f1 <(echo "") f2
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

Comment: Every once in a while the old guys remember a trick or two :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, A Simple idea would be to create a 3rd file with an empty line or 2 and add it in the middle....